# Using "no longer" with future events: simple, progressive, or passive?

Tags: modal-verbs, passive-voice, past-participles, progressive-aspect

Which of the following sentences is correct?

1. *Simple*: You will **no longer work** your Friday shift.
2. *Progressive*: You will **be no longer working** your Friday shift.
3. *Passive*: You will **no longer be worked** your Friday shift.

Comment: I think the correct one is the second, am I right?
you will be no longer working your Friday shift

Comment: Either the first or second would work, but change the word order in the second to "You will no longer be working ..."